# Iterate and update cells based on other cell conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure how to iterate a dataframe row by row and update cell values based on conditions from other cells.
If a partial string is found in one cell and if simultaneously another cell has a specific value then I should add a specific value to a cell

Have tried also:

```
for i, row in df3.iterrows():
    codmarime = ''
    if df3['20755' in df3['ITEM CODE'][i]] and df3['24' in df3['TG'][i]]: 
       codmarime= '002'
       df3['SKU'][i] = '20'+str(df3['ITEM CODE'][i])+str(df3['COLOR CODE'][i])+codmarime


for i, row in df3.iterrows():
    codmarime = '' 
    if df3['ITEM CODE'].str.contains("20755") and df3['TG'].str.contains("24"): 
       codmarime= '002'
       df3['SKU'][i] = '20'+str(df3['ITEM CODE'][i])+str(df3['COLOR CODE'][i])+codmarime
    elif df3['ITEM CODE'].str.contains("20755") and df3['TG'].str.contains("25"): 
       codmarime= '003'
       df3['SKU'][i] = '20'+str(df3['ITEM CODE'][i])+str(df3['COLOR CODE'][i])+codmarime
```

Output

```
> ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)
> 
> ----> 6     if df3['ITEM CODE'].str.contains("20755") and df3['TG'].str.contains("24"):
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you can add a data(sample) and expected output by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) . Also use `&` in boolean conditions not `and`

Comment: Please correctly format your output.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains e.g. `for i, row in df3.iterrows():` loop.
Inside this loop `row` refers to the current row.

So instead of e.g. `df3['SKU'][i]` you should use `row['SKU']` or even `row.SKU`.

Take analogous approach to other cases of read/write from columns of the current
row.